# Laravel 5.2 - how to copy user data from external database with different table format

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have created a new project with laravel 5.2 which have `users` table containing `id, email, password` as provided in `database/migration/2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table`. I also added some fields such as fullname and address.

I also have old project with different table format and fields in its users table. Now, I need to copy / migrate all users information such as email, fullname, etc into my new project using laravel.

I know laravel provides seeding and multiple database connection. But I am not sure if it is ok to use seed with **10K records**. Please advise the good way to copy those thousands records.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you able to access this table from your Laravel project?

Comment: yes accessible using 2nd connection as `Schema::connection('mysql2')`, but where should i perform the query to copy and insert to default database connection? thanks @Daniel

Comment: 10K records is a lot and could lead to performance issues. If needed and you have upgraded to Laravel >= 6 by now, please take a look into `lazy collections`: https://josephsilber.com/posts/2020/07/29/lazy-collections-in-laravel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good candidate for a Console Command.

`php artisan make:console YourCommandName`

```
public function handle()
{
    $mysql2 = DB::connection('mysql2')->select("var1 AS var2...")->get()->toArray();

    NewModel::insert($mysql2);
}
```

This is somewhat pseudo code. I haven't tested it, but that's how I would do it.

The other option is to create a new model in a foreach loop.

```
foreach ($mysql2 as $record)
{
    $model = new LaravelModel();
    $model->property = $record->property;
    $model->save();
}
```